# DLL Not Found (AlphaVSS.x64.dll)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dll, vss

I downloaded the AlphaVSS dll and example from (http://alphavss.alphaleonis.com/) to my windows 7 laptop (x64). When I run the example AlphaShadow create c: from an administrator command prompt everything works fine.

If I copy that same folder to a windows server 2012 R2 machine I get a file not found exception 'AlphaVSS.x64.dll' not found.

I've tried install the c+ redistribution pack (someone somewhere suggested that) but that didn't help.

I've also changed the file permissions to get everyone full control, didn't help.

Any ideas or pointers where to look to find more information ?

- unblocking the files does nothing

**I was using the Debug version not the build version (I have VS on my laptop)**

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please note that it says “file ... or one of its dependencies”. Hence the suggestion to install the C++ redistribution package. Which build (Debug/Release) did you try?

Comment: Try to [unblock files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile.aspx) (preferably `zip` file before unpacking, otherwise you'll have to do it for each file).

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) can help you determine what is different about the two system configurations.  Visual C++  Redist  has multiple versions, they are all separate, so you could have installed the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

The debug version of alphavss requires dlls from VS installed, the release version worked just fine.

Thanks everyone